# Slick2d: How to restart a game state?

Tags: java, state, restart, slick2d

I'm making a `StateBasedGame` in Java - Slick2d. I need to restart the state completley after I use the `enterState()` method. Some posts say I should override the `enterState` method, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i found out. I need to re-initialize the state using the init method. Here's the code:

```
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
                    throws SlickException
    {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        if(input.isKeyPressed( Input.KEY_SPACE ))
        {
            sbg.getState( Main.play ).init(container, sbg);
            sbg.enterState( Main.play );

        }

    }
```